# PHP How to find a string within a string that doesn't occur next to a letter

Tags: php, string

A recent problem I've encountered

```
$string = 'Demetria Devonne';

if (strpos($string, 'Devon'))
{
    echo 'Devon';
}
```

Returns a result. But I need to only find matches for the specified word where a letter does not come before or after.

So running a check on words like

```
"Devons" or "Devonia"
```

would not result in a match.

But then something like

```
"From Devon, Uk"
```

would result in a match as there are no letters surrounding it.

Is there a function that can do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to do this using regex, rather than string functions. Fortunately, this is very simple in this case.

```
if (preg_match('/\bDevon\b/', $string)) {
    echo 'Devon';
}
```

`\b` is a special character that means "word boundary", such as a comma or a space.

Answer (score 0):

use str_word_count() instead. u get array with words, and then u can use in_array() to check if ur word is there :s

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using strstr() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
echo $domain; // prints @example.com
```

Mixing it with substr : `substr(strstr($string, 'Devon'),0,5)` could do the job